# Double action on HTML form submit button

Tags: html, forms

I am currently trying to submit form data to a third party site from our own wordpress based website.

I need it to open in a new blank window or tab. I am able to do this so far using a target="_blank" on the form itself.

The tricky part is I also want the data to save on my own site.

The only way I know how to do this double action is to hook in after the post is saved on my site but this means the form is submitted to my own site and then I use javascript or something to redirect to the third party site but this creates pop up warnings which I can't have in this case...

Does anybody have any ideas around this and if I have not been detailed enough please don't hesitate to ask me more info.

Thanks

Comment: Honestly, I would approach this differently. I would POST to your own site first (in a new window), then the server-side handler would POST the data to the third-party site, and then redirect you to the third-party site (with GET, obviously).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps submit by AJAX first to the local site, then -- on success -- submit the form & navigate them whole page to the other domain?

With jQuery:

```
<form id='form' method='post' action='http://remote.website.com/send-data-here'>
    <input ...>
    <input ...>
    ...
    <button type='button' onclick='doubleSubmit();'>Submit</button>
</form>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    var LOCAL_URL = "/myForm-receiver.php";
    function doubleSubmit() {
        var data = $('#form').serialize();
        $.post( LOCAL_URL, data, new function(response){
            // Successfully posted by AJAX to Local Website;
            //  -- now POST the form to the destination site, 
            //  -- & navigate to that result page.
            $('#form).submit();
        });
    }
</script>
```

I'm assuming you want to receive a copy of the data locally, but the user will navigate to the destination domain for the "result page".

Comment: Your assumption is correct. Store locally as a lead... we want to know the transaction has taken place and the info is then sent on to a partner's website. This solution looks to be exactly what I need. Thank you very much for your time. I think this will be perfect.

Answer (score 0):

Need to submit the data through ajax and saved the data in your data base then redirect to third party url or submit to there use like `jQuery(selector).ajax(dataString:--);`

may this help you thanks!

Comment: I am looking in to this now. Thank you for your answer. I am going to do some research on JQuery/ajax solutions.